# Why does it not allow me to input values past [1][0]?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row1,col1,row2,col2,a,b;
    int matrix1[row1][col1];
    int matrix2[row2][col2];
    int num;
    int val;


    
    cout<<"\nEnter matrix 1 dimensions in 'row column' format(example: 2 3): ";
    cin>>row1>>col1;
    
    cout<<"\nInput values for matrix 1:- \n";
    for(a=0;a<row1;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<col1;b++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter value for index ["<<a<<"]["<<b<<"]: ";
            cin>>matrix1[a][b];
        }
        
    } 
}
```

When I start putting in values, the program always stops after I put in the first value of the second row. Why?

[image]

Comment: Not only are VLAs a non-standard feature, but you're using uninitialized values to set the sizes of the VLAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int row1,col1,row2,col2,a,b;
> int matrix1[row1][col1];
> ```

How big do you think these arrays are? C++ is not a "dataflow" language where you can use a variable and the runtime would pause the execution until you initialise the value later. Instead, the variable is read immediately and if the variable isn't initialised - such as it isn't in this case - then the behaviour of the program is undefined. Don't do this.

Furthermore, the size of an array variable must be compile time constant. User input is never compile time constant. The example program is ill-formed in C++.

> [I observed some behaviour]. Why?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

You must first determine the size of the arrays.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row1,col1,row2,col2;
    cout<<"\nEnter matrix 1 dimensions in 'row column' format(example: 2 3): ";
    cout<<"\nInput values for matrix 1:- \n";
    cin>>row1>>col1;
    int matrix1[row1][col1];
    int matrix2[row2][col2];
    int num;
    int val;
    for(int a=0;a<row1;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<col1;b++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter value for index ["<<a<<"]["<<b<<"]: ";
            cin>>matrix1[a][b];
        }
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: VLAs are not part of the c++ standart.

Comment: Two dimensional VLAs also have tendency to blow up the stack. Also `row2` and `col2` are used before being initialized.

Answer (score -2):

For row1 , col1 ,row2,col2 only declaration is done .Space is not assigned .
It will be like mat1[row1][col1] .But it should be like mat1[2][3]. So to declare a matrix the variables assigned to define the size must be declared and initialised and then need to be used.

```
Below code might work :

    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int row1,col1,row2,col2,a,b;
        int num;
        int val;
        cout<<"\nEnter matrix 1 dimensions in 'row column' format(example: 2 3): ";
        cin>>row1>>col1;
        
        int matrix1[row1][col1];
        cout<<"\nInput values for matrix 1:- \n";
        for(a=0;a<row1;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<col1;b++)
            {
                 cout<<"Enter value for index ["<<a<<"]["<<b<<"]: ";
                cin>>matrix1[a][b];
            }
    
        } 
    }
```

Comment: VLAs are still not part of C++ and have a tendency to blow up the stack.

Comment: Please don't put text in code examples, it also seems that your answer is not correct